# How do I parse a float from a string that might contain left-over characters without doing manual parsing?

Tags: rust, floating-point

How do I parse a float from a string that may contain left-over characters, and figure out where it ends, without doing manual parsing (e.g. `parseFloat()` in JS)?

An example would be the string `"2e-1!"`. I want to evaluate the *next float* from the string such that I can split this string into `"2e-1"` and `"!"` (for example, if I wanted to implement a calculator.) How would I do this *without* writing a parser to see where the float ends, taking that as an `&str`, and then using `.parse()`?

I am aware that this means that I may have to parse nonstandard things such as `"3e+1+e3"` to `3e+1` (`30`) and `"+e3"`. This is intended; I do not know all of the ways to format floating point numbers, especially the ones valid to Rust's `parse::<f64>()`, but I want to handle them regardless.

How can I do this, preferably without external libraries?

Comment: _"How can I do this, preferably without external libraries?"_ -- without libraries, the way you do it is to write some code that does what you just described. Otherwise, maybe try something like [nom](https://docs.rs/nom/5.0.0/nom/).

Comment: There isn't a reasonable way to satisfy your requirements without using an external crate. I mean, you can just drop characters from the end of the string until it parses as a float, but that doesn't really count as reasonable.

Comment: I think that what you want is similar to the C function `strtof`, so you could try calling that, if you count `libc` as not external...

Comment: @SvenMarnach depending on the ratio of number length to string length, parsing from the start until it doesn't work anymore might be less inefficient, though you'd have the issue of having to "skip" some invalid states and keep going (e.g. 2e and 2e- would not parse but 2e-1 would)

Comment: Supposedly the `parse::<f64>()` already knows how to parse an `f64` and by implication where the number ends , so it does not make sense to have to replicate part of its behavior (finding the end of the number). None of the answers so far seem to address this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to either implement your own floating-point parser or use an external library. The parser in the standard library [always errors out when it encounters additional junk in the input string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/num/dec2flt/parse.rs.html) – it doesn't even allow leading or trailing whitespace.

A good external crate to use is `nom`. It comes with an [integrated parser for floating-point numbers](https://docs.rs/nom/5.1.2/nom/number/complete/fn.double.html) that meets your requirements. Examples:

```
use nom::number::complete::double;
let parser = double::<_, ()>;
assert_eq!(parser("2.0 abc"), Ok((" abc", 2.0)));
let result = parser("Nanananananana hey, Jude!").unwrap();
assert_eq!(result.0, "ananananana hey, Jude!");
assert!(result.1.is_nan());
```

The parser expects the floating-point number at the very beginning of the string. If you want to allow leading whitespace, you can remove it first using `trim_start()`.