# Parse an integer, ignoring any non-numeric suffix

Tags: rust

I have a list of strings all starting with a number. However, I do not know what they end with. Some examples might be `"12/1/1"`, `"33"`, or `"17abc"`. I want to read the number at the start of each string, turning the examples into `12`, `33`, and `17` respectively.

I have gotten it to work with the code below.

```rust
"12/1/1".chars().take_while(|c| c.is_numeric()).collect::<String>().parse::<usize>()
```

However, I do feel like a more efficient/cleaner solution exists. One without the collection of the String and/or not as verbose.
I would prefer not to use any external crates.

Comment: Define "better". Do you mean without the clone? With _less_ code? Are external crates allowed?

Comment: It's great that you have a solution to your question! You should post it as an answer rather than an part of your question and then potentially accept that answer. That way, the question shows up as solved in search results, people can vote on your answer, and your solution can be more helpful to future people with the same problem.

Comment: Closely related (with a float instead of an integer): [How do I parse a float from a string that might contain left-over characters without doing manual parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64465527/how-do-i-parse-a-float-from-a-string-that-might-contain-left-over-characters-wit)

Comment: @vallentin I've updated my question to not use "better"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your definition of "better". If you simply want to remove the needless `String` creation, then you can use [`atoi` crate](https://crates.io/crates/atoi).

Alternatively, you can also use the [`nom` crate](https://crates.io/crates/nom), and use [`digit0()`](https://docs.rs/nom/6.0.1/nom/character/complete/fn.digit0.html) to create your own `atoi()` function:

```rust
// nom = "6.0"
use nom::character::complete::digit0;
use nom::error::Error;
use std::str::FromStr;

fn atoi<F: FromStr>(input: &str) -> Result<F, <F as FromStr>::Err> {
    digit0::<_, Error<_>>(input).unwrap().1.parse::<F>()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", atoi::<usize>("12/1/1")); // Prints `Ok(12)`
    println!("{:?}", atoi::<usize>("33"));     // Prints `Ok(33)`
    println!("{:?}", atoi::<usize>("17abc"));  // Prints `Ok(17)`
    println!("{:?}", atoi::<usize>("abc"));    // Prints `Err(ParseIntError { kind: Empty })`
    println!("{:?}", atoi::<usize>(""));       // Prints `Err(ParseIntError { kind: Empty })`
}
```

The `unwrap()` is safe, as if there are no digits then `Ok` is still returned, and the empty string is handled by [`parse()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse).

---

Since you don't want to use any external crates, then instead you can use [`find()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.find) to get the index of the first non-numeric character.

Note that, @AlexLarionov's answer panics on overflow, while this one does not.

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;

fn atoi<F: FromStr>(input: &str) -> Result<F, <F as FromStr>::Err> {
    let i = input.find(|c: char| !c.is_numeric()).unwrap_or_else(|| input.len());
    input[..i].parse::<F>()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", atoi::<usize>("12/1/1")); // Prints `Ok(12)`
    println!("{:?}", atoi::<usize>("33"));     // Prints `Ok(33)`
    println!("{:?}", atoi::<usize>("17abc"));  // Prints `Ok(17)`
    println!("{:?}", atoi::<usize>("abc"));    // Prints `Err(ParseIntError { kind: Empty })`
    println!("{:?}", atoi::<usize>(""));       // Prints `Err(ParseIntError { kind: Empty })`

    println!("{:?}", atoi::<usize>("123456789101112131415"));
    // Prints `Err(ParseIntError { kind: PosOverflow })`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In nightly version of Rust you can use experimental [`map_while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map_while) on iterators to solve the problem quite fancy by mapping each digit character to an integer number (until we can't to do it, i.e. `c.to_digit(10)` returns `None`). Then we construct the final number using `fold`.

```rust
#![feature(iter_map_while)]

fn main() {
    let number = "12/1/1"
        .chars()
        .map_while(|c| c.to_digit(10))
        .fold(0, |acc, digit| acc * 10 + digit);
    println!("{}", number); // 12
}
```

Notice that there is no creation of a separate `String`, which is preferable, since creating many of them on the heap takes quite some time (relatively to just dealing with numbers on stack).

In stable Rust it's a bit more verbose:

```rust
fn main() {
    let number = "12/1/1"
        .chars()
        .map(|c| c.to_digit(10))
        .take_while(|opt| opt.is_some())
        .fold(0, |acc, digit| acc * 10 + digit.unwrap());
    println!("{}", number); // 12
}
```

Comment: Warning: This will panic if the integer overflows.

Comment: This answer is closest to what I imagined (with dropping the extra String). But it is a bit on the verbose side. If no other answers comes up, I'll accept this.

Comment: @Netråm well, you have the non-ordinary task, obviously you'll have to program it in some way. In the end, if something is verbose, hide it behind a function

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for Regular Expressions (Regex) to me. All you want is to get the first group of numerics so you could use the "/d" (integers) descriptor or use "[0-9]" (the range of characters between 0 and 9 inclusive) and then "+" to show you want the character class to repeat 1 or more times.

I'm not a Rust programmer so I can't help you too much with the details but you can find Regex documentation for Rust here: https://docs.rs/regex/1.4.2/regex/