# Parse integer from from iterator

Tags: rust

Is there a way to parse an integer from a `str` in rust, like `my_str.parse()`, but yielding an iterator to the point after the parsed integer? Something like this:

```rust
let my_str = "1234x";
let mut iter = my_str.chars();

assert_eq!(iter.parse_and_advance().unwrap(), 1234);
assert_eq!(iter.next(), Some('x'));
```

Comment: Why not just iterate and skip the digit characters (plus `-` sign)?  `iter.skip_while(|&c| c == '-' || c.is_numeric())`

Comment: That makes sense; is there a way to convert that back into a ```Chars``` iterator for the remaining elements?

Comment: This isn't possible as requested given the signature of `Iterator` -- there's no way that the parsing code could know it's reached the end of the number without getting to the `'x'`, and once it has there's no way for it to put the `'x'` back into the iterator. This would require a `Peekable` to work. (`my_str.chars().peekable()`)

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Note your code incorrectly skips something like `12-1`.

Comment: Related: [Parse an integer, ignoring any non-numeric suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65601579/parse-an-integer-ignoring-any-non-numeric-suffix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need iterators at all. You can first use `str::find` to find the first non-numeric value, then use `str::split_at` to split the string there so you can parse the first half and convert the second half into an iterator:

```rust
let str = "1234x";
let non_letter = str.find(|c: char| c != '-' && !c.is_numeric());
let (num, rest) = str.split_at(non_letter.unwrap_or(str.len()));
let num: i32 = num.parse().unwrap();
let mut rest = rest.chars();
assert_eq!(num, 1234);
assert_eq!(rest.next(), Some('x'));
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5005984360dcf1e17d6bcdea0ea074ac)

Note that, as stated in the comments, [there's a little more nuance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65601579/5923139) than this to extracting the initial number, but depending on your usecase it won't be an issue.

Comment: Note that your code scans the number twice. This is not necessarily a disadvantage, just something to note.